# How to explain the difference between parameter and hyperparameter in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter

In practice, this difference is obvious, but how to put it in words?

Comment: I think this blog page summarizes it quite well: https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-between-a-parameter-and-a-hyperparameter/

Answer (score 1):

I would describe hyper parameters as "indirectly learned/trained". Think of the inference chain.

Data --> Parameter(s) --> Hyper parameter(s)

The hyper parameters are not directly connected to the data observed.

Another way is to consider a scenario where you know the parameter(s). Is there any point using the data? If the answer is no, then it's a hyper parameter.